# How to convert smallint to string?

Tags: javascript, string, sqlite

I have column “ALAT_STATUS”  in table VIEW_ALAT. I would like to import the column “ALAT_STATUS” in the website. Then, I want to convert the value in the column from smallint datatype to string datatype. However the code did not work.

So, this is the code :

```
 function setOptionStatus(){

 var s = "select [ALAT_STATUS] BUTIR,[ALAT_STATUS] KOD from ALAT group by ALAT_STATUS"

                            if (s == '1') {'AKTIF'}
                                            else if (s == '2') { 'ROSAK'} 
                                              else { 'LUPUS'}

                            var u = SRV_REQ_MS + "type=grid&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(s);
    $.getJSON(u, function (STATUS) {
         $dss.setSelectOption('searchStatus',STATUS, '');                 
    })              
}
```

I would appreciate your answer. Thank you!